# Splitting Full Name column into 3 columns: 'Full Name', 'First Name' and 'Last Name' and getting error: bad character in group name 'First Name'

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split a column named Full Name into 3 separate columns:
Full Name  First Name  Last Name
and I am using this code to make those three columns:

```
column_indices = [0,26,27,28]

new_names = ['Respondent Submission Date','Email   Primary','Full Name','Employee ID']
old_names = df4.columns[column_indices]
df4.rename(columns=dict(zip(old_names, new_names)), inplace=True)

print(df4)

#df4.to_csv(NewExcelPathName)

(df4.iloc[:, 27].str.extract(r'(?P<First Name>\w+) (?P<Last Name>\w+)$', expand=True))
```

The console returns:
error: bad character in group name 'First Name'

> error: bad character in group name 'First Name'

How can I fix this line:

```
(df4.iloc[:, 27].str.extract(r'(?P<First Name>\w+) (?P<Last Name>\w+)$', expand=True))
```

I copied and edited this line from https://moonbooks.org/Articles/How-to-split-a-full-name-column-into-a-first-and-last-name-columns-with-pandas-in-python-/

As this code ensures that for people with more than two names in their full name, their last name is the last word.

**EDIT**

I can now split Full Name into two additional columns called First Name and Last Name

I am now trying to make sure that for people that have names like John Wayne Smith, that the last name is Smith and not Wayne.

This is now the following code I am using:

```
column_indices = [0,26,27,28]

new_names = ['Respondent Submission Date','Email   Primary','Full Name','Employee ID']
old_names = df4.columns[column_indices]
df4.rename(columns=dict(zip(old_names, new_names)), inplace=True)
print(df4['Full Name'].str.split(' ', expand = True))
df4[['First Name', 'Last Name']] = df4['Full Name'].str.split(' ', expand = True)
print(df4)
```

and my Output is:

```
  Email   Primary  Full Name Employee ID Timestamp Of Last Metadata Update  \
2             NaN  Test Name         NaN                               NaN   
3             NaN        NaN         NaN                               NaN   
4             NaN        NaN         NaN                               NaN   
5             NaN        NaN         NaN                               NaN   

  First Name Last Name  
2       Test      Name  
3        NaN       NaN  
4        NaN       NaN  
5        NaN       NaN
```

Comment: ```df4['Full_Name'].str.extract(r'(?P<First_Name>\w+) (?P<Last_Name>\w+)', expand=True)```
The example you showed, he is changing the column names after split,

if you give me a df to recreate, i will do it for you

Comment: Actually thanks to your input I can now split Full Name into first name and last name. How can I add these two new columns alongside Full Name in the dataframe?

Comment: I'm sorry, i can't understand
If there are common columns, you can join
But that wouldn't be the case here, it should be in the same dataframe

Comment: I have successfully added two new columns alongside the Full Name in the dataframe using a split() function. Now now last step is to ensure that for people that have names like John Wayne Smith, that the last name is Smith and not Wayne.
This is the code:
`df4[['First Name', 'Last Name']] = df4['Full Name'].str.split(' ', expand = True)`
how can I edit 'First Name', 'Last Name' in that line to make that happen?
I have tried replacing it with
`r'(?P<First_Name>\w+) (?P<Last_Name>\w+)'`
but I get a value error columns must be the same length as the key.

Comment: Can you update the question show your current output and required output?

Comment: and what's the required output?

Comment: The output should be the same, the only difference would be that if the column `'Full Name'` contained a cell called `Test Name One`, I want `'Test'` to be displayed in the `'First Name'` Column and `'One'` to be displayed in the `'Last Name'` column instead of `'Name'`

Comment: try this ```df = df[['First Name','Last Name' 'Primary','Email','Employee ID','Timestamp Of Last Metadata Update']]``` if this doesn't work, maybe i would be able to help better on a short call gmeet/zoom anything is fine